# Javascript to set cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-translate

I am trying to have a javascript set a cookie that tells Google Translate which language to set the page.

I have tried this based on my browser's cookie when selecting a language.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  setcookie(“googtrans”, “/en/fr”, time()+3600, “/”, “www.example.com”);
  setcookie(“googtrans”, “/en/fr”, time()+3600, “/”, “.example.com”);
});

</script>
```

I am not very good with javascript and I get an unexpected token ILLEGAL, not sure what this means:

```
<script>(function() {with (this[2]) {with (this[1]) {with (this[0]) {return function(event) {ccm_exitVersionList()
};}}}})</script>
```

Is my script wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: On the first hand, what is `this` in your script above? On the other hand, try not to use `with` keyword cause it's deprecated, read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). In the end, you should be careful with those quotes around your strings: `“`, they're illegal characters as string delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript strings must be quoted with `"` (QUOTATION MARK) or `'` (APOSTROPHE) not `“` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) and `”` (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK).

This error is typically caused by writing code using a word processor that automatically inserts typographic quotes.

Use a text editor designed for programmers (such as Sublime, Vim, Emacs, Komodo, TextMate, Notepad++, BBEdit, or Eclipse) instead.

Comment: This is working, just wondering if you know why I get, Uncaught ReferenceError: setcookie is not defined.

Comment: Presumably because you haven't written a (or loaded a third party) `setcookie` function. It isn't native JavaScript or a standard browser API.

Comment: Do you know how to write or load the third party function?

Comment: It is my understanding this would not be legal, so I won't be pursuing.

Comment: There's nothing illegal about cookies. The EU just has some (pretty stupid) rules about consent for cookies (not helped by browsers simplifying their native cookie management features) requiring that you display a disclaimer and allow users to opt-out.